# How to put external credentials salesforces api token access

Tags: api, httprequest, screen-flow

I'm new to Salesforce and my task is to create a flow that makes an HTTP callout to a private API.

- To access the API, one needs to create an account and obtain a token which is valid for 7 days.
- I've obtained the token and tested the requests on Postman, everything works as expected.
- Then, I followed tutorials to create a flow with an HTTP callout action, so I created an external credential and a named credential. I granted the necessary permission sets, but I'm unsure at which point I'm supposed to provide the access token.
- Initially, I tried adding it to the external credential with a custom authentication protocol by entering my key, but despite that, when I test my request, I still get the message saying that I don't have authorized access

[image]

Comment: does the permission set include Read on `UserExternalCredential` object?